# Looping over data in leaflet

Tags: javascript, loops, leaflet

I have 1000 geographic data points and I have a US map. I want to create tiny circles at each of these 1000 geo data points. My data is in geojson format.
I am able create a circle at one point at a time. But how do I loop over the dataset to create circles at each point?

This is my circle code:

```
var circle = L.circle([64.837778, -147.716389], 500, {
        color: 'black',
        fillColor: '#000',
        fillOpacity: 0.8
    }).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [L.GeoJSON](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson) to render your data. It was made for rendering GeoJSON data. It has a pointToLayer function which you can use to render your point to circles, circlemarkers or whatever you desire. As a matter of fact the examples section on the Leaflet website has an exact example of what you are trying to accomplish:

```
L.geoJson(someGeojsonFeature, {
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        return L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions);
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

You can render single features or entire featureCollections with the GeoJSON layer, check out the examples on the site: http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson.html

EDIT: as per request, an entire example:

First you start of with a GeoJSON featureCollection:

```
var featureCollection = [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {},
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-104.99, 39.73]
    }
},{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {},
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-104.96, 39.73]
    }
}];
```

Instanciate GeoJSON layer with the featureCollection:

```
var geoJsonLayer = L.geoJson(featureCollection, {
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
            radius: 8,
            fillColor: "#ff7800",
            color: "#000",
            weight: 1,
            opacity: 1,
            fillOpacity: 0.8
        });
    }
});
```

Add the layer to your map instance:

```
geoJsonLayer.addTo(map);
```

Working example on plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/RzYMrkkly3DdHMnkjvVN?p=preview

Comment: I've tried doing this:  `var latlng = L.latLng(ufodata);  
    
  var geojsonMarkerOptions = {  
   radius: 8,  
   fillColor: "#ff7800",  
   color: "#000",  
   weight: 1,  
   opacity: 1,  
   fillOpacity: 0.8  
  };  
    
  L.geoJson(latlng, {  
   pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng)   {  
    return L.circleMarker(latlng,   geojsonMarkerOptions);  
   }  
  }).addTo(map);  `

Comment: I recommend reading the entire GeoJSON example and reference. The first parameter when creating an instance is for GeoJSON features or featureCollections, not latlng objects. See: [http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson.html](http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson.html) and [http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson)

Comment: Thanks again. I've gone through them but I don't fully comprehend. Can you help me get a start?   Where is the data going in this code? when you say some geojson feature, you mean a feature from the data right??